# Smallest number of poset that represents a set of permutations

Tags: combinatorics

I'm interested in compact representations of permutations, e.g. the set {a.b, b.a} can be represented as the partial order where a and b are unordered since the set of linear extensions of that partial order is the original set. Can someone provide results about:
1) The cardinality of the set of posets whose union of linear extensions correspond to an initial set of permutations;
2) Considering the set of sets of posets that satisfy this property, is there a minimal element in the number of posets?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to clarify what you're asking. You take a partially ordered set $(A,R)$. Then you consider the collection $F_R$ of all total orderings $\leq$ of $A$ such that whenever $x R y$, we must also have $x \leq y$. Then you ask how many order relations $R$ there are such that $F_R$ satisfies a certain condition about corresponding "to an initial set of permutations."  I don't understand what condition you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me try and clarify the question. Let X be a set of permutations (total orders), e.g. {abc, cba, abc, ...}. If one considers the intersection of the elements of X, we obtain a partial order (A,R). Consider Y to be the set of linear extensions of (A,R). It is definitely possible for X \subset Y. This means that a *single* partial order does not represent only the set X (which is the property of interest). The question is: what is the smallest number of partials (A_i, R_i) such that the union of their linear extensions is X?

Comment: Okay, let me recap what I understand so far. You have a fixed finite set $A$, say $A = \{1,2\dots,n\}$. (I'm not sure about the $A_i$'s you mentioned.) You also have a set $X$ of total orderings of $A$. You would like to select a number $R_1, R_2, \dots, R_m$ of partial orderings on $A$, with $m$ as small as possible, so that a certain set $Y$ of total orderings of $A$ is equal to $X$. I believe you're saying that a total ordering belongs to $Y$ if and only if it is an extension of *at least one* of the $R_i$'s. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The set $X$ that you mention must be the union of the extensions of $R_i$'s. Also, ideally you want the intersection of the linear extensions of two orderings in $R_i$ to be empty.

Comment: I don't know anything about this topic, but my guess would be that if there is any result at all on this, the best case would be the existence of some bound on $m$, not necessarily a formula for $m$, which would have to depend on $X$ in some way. Are you interested in mathematical results like that, or are you more interested in having an efficient algorithm—if one exists—to find the sets $R_i$ for a given set $X$?

Comment: I'm interested in any result in this area.

Comment: Okay, I would suggest the following formulation. "Representation of a set of total orderings by a set of partial orderings. Let $A$ be a set with $n$ elements and $X$ a collection of total orderings of $A$. I am interested in collections $Y = \{R_1,\dots,R_m\}$ of partial orderings of $A$ with the property that $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^m \{ T \mid \text{$T$ is a total ordering of $A$ extending $R_i$} \}$. In particular, I would like to hear about any known bounds on how small $m$ can be chosen, or similar results." If you still don't get any answers here, you can cross-post to Computer Science.